# How to fix "failed to initialize intent(inout|inplace|cache) array, input not an array" who appears after using fmin_l_bfgs_b?

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

I'm trying to use scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b function in order to minimize my function evaluateFunc(params) which returns an error and the related error gradient.

However, when I call the function fmin_l_bfgs_b with this function, it send me this message : "failed to initialize intent(inout|inplace|cache) array, input not an array".

I think the issue comes from my parameters so I try to change them into numpy.array, list. My parameters "params" and "bounds" have the same size. I call the function like this:

```py
params, minval, infos = fmin_l_bfgs_b(evaluateFunc, params, bounds=bounds)
```

where params looks like [0.3467169328403201, 0.3467936178031559, 0.5473515530057025,...]

and bounds [(None, None), (0, None), (0, None), ...]